# metaprogramming, factorial, C++, boost

Tags: c++, boost, metaprogramming

Need to cacl factorial of all numbers from 1 to k and save them in mpl container using boost/mpl.

Range of this nums storaged in range_c.
The difficulty is that I have to storage all previous values:
`k! = (k-1)!*k`

I thought that I will storage previous values in mpl::vector_c, i.e. each iteration I will take value from source range_c and multiplie it with previous value `(k-1)!` which contains in vector_c, but I have a lot of mistakes in this code:

```
namespace mpl = boost::mpl;
const int border = 10;
using namespace mpl;

typedef
    range_c <int, 1, border>
Numbers;

typedef vector_c<int, 1> data;

typedef
   mpl::transform
  <
    Numbers,
    data,
    push_back<data, multiplies <_, _>>,
    back_inserter
    <
      mpl::vector <>
    >
  >::type
    Factorials;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all implementations factorial was calculated for each number from 1. In the task i need to calc each next factorial by multiplication with previous factorial. Here right code:

```
namespace mpl = boost::mpl;
using namespace mpl;
const int border = 15;

typedef range_c<int, 1, border> nums;
typedef vector<int_<1>> data;

typedef mpl::fold<
    nums, data,
    mpl::push_back<_1, mpl::multiplies<_2, back<_1>>>
>::type Factorials;
```

Comment: What did you use to compile your code? For me compilation fails in VS2013 and gcc4.8.2 using boost 1.56

Comment: Here all code, if it helps.[link](http://pastebin.com/uAciAa3B)
I compiled with VS13 using boost 1.58

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following:

```
namespace detail
{
    // General computation of factorial
    template <std::size_t N>
    struct factorial :
        std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N * factorial<N - 1>::value>
    {
    };

    // special case for 0
    template <>
    struct factorial<0> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 1u>
    {};

    // helper to create the sequence of factorial value
    template <typename T> struct factorial_seq_impl;

    template <std::size_t...Is>
    struct factorial_seq_impl<std::index_sequence<Is...>>{
        using type = std::index_sequence<factorial<Is>::value...>;
    };

}

// And finally
template <std::size_t N>
using factorial_seq =
    typename detail::factorial_seq_impl<std::make_index_sequence<N>>::type;

static_assert(std::is_same<std::index_sequence<1, 1, 2, 6, 24>, factorial_seq<5>>::value, "");
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/LBVOuZ).

Comment: I think in this code factorial of each number calcs every time from 1, i mean that:
1! = 1,
2! = 1 * 2,
3! = 1 * 2 * 3,
...
But i need to calc factorial by this algorithm:
1) Calc 1!,
2) Save 1! in container,
3) Calc 2! using 1! We have already calced it, there is no nessary to calc it again, so we can take from container: 
    2! = 1!*2,
4) Save 2! in container,
5) Calc 3! using 2!, We have already calced it, there is no nessary to calc it again, so we can take from container: 
    3! = 2!*3,
But how can i do that? Calc Factorials without repeating calculations

Comment: There are all intantiated only once. So currently, I instantiate `N` factorials from `0` to `N - 1`, an intermediate `index_sequence<0, .., N - 1>` and the resulting `index_sequence<0!, 1!, (N - 1)!>`.

Comment: I understand.. But, maybe you know how to do that with boost and C++11? Because my teacher requires only boost and very aggressive to C++14.

Comment: @ДмитрийЕрмолаев: The only thing I use from C++14 is `make_index_sequence` which can be written in C++11 easily.

Answer (score 0):

A factorial mpl version and a collection of first 10 results in a vector:

```
template <typename current, typename to, typename result>
struct calc :
    eval_if< less_equal< current, to >,
    calc< typename current::next, to, typename multiplies< result, current > >,
    result
    >::type
{};

template<typename value>
struct factorial :
    calc<int_<1>, value, int_<1> >::type
{};

template <>
struct factorial<int_<0> > :
    int_<1>::type
{};

template <>
struct factorial<int_<1> > :
    int_<1>::type
{};

template <int value>
struct factorial_c :
    factorial<int_<value> >::type
{};

struct factorial_collection_10 :
    transform<
    range_c<int, 0, 10>,
    factorial<boost::mpl::_1>,
    back_inserter<vector0<> >
    >::type
{};
```

Test code:

```
int main()
{
    // get 5! value
    std::cout << "5! = " << factorial_c<5>::value << std::endl;

    // access 6th element of the factorial collection
    std::cout << "6! = " << at<factorial_collection_10, int_<6> >::type::value << std::endl;

    // copy factorial collection to std vector to check values at runtime
    std::vector<int> factorialVec;
    for_each< factorial_collection_10, boost::mpl::_1 >(boost::bind(static_cast<void(std::vector<int>::*)(const int&)>(&std::vector<int>::push_back), &factorialVec, boost::lambda::_1));

    std::cout << "First 10 factorial numbers: " << std::endl;
    for (std::size_t x = 0; x < factorialVec.size(); ++x)
        std::cout << x << "! = " << factorialVec[x] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
5! = 120
6! = 720
First 10 factorial numbers:
0! = 1
1! = 1
2! = 2
3! = 6
4! = 24
5! = 120
6! = 720
7! = 5040
8! = 40320
```